# Why are the DIV not lining up next to each other

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```
<div id="dvFirst" class="mainSecond" style="background: #6FA5FD;">
            <div id="leftdiv3" class="leftdiv">Client: </div>
            <div id="rightdiv3" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCliNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select" ></asp:DropDownList></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvSecond" class="mainSecond" style="background: #f00">
            <div id="leftdiv4" class="leftdiv">Site: </div>
            <div id="rightdiv4" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSitNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></div>
        </div>
       <div id="dvThird" class="mainSecond" style="background: #808080">
            <div id="leftdiv5" class="leftdiv">Provider: </div>
            <div id="rightdiv5" class="rightdiv"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvFourth" class="mainFirst" style="background: #b6ff00">
            <div id="leftdiv1" class="leftdiv">Message: </div>
            <div id="rightdiv1" class="rightdiv"><asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dvFifth" class="mainSecond" style="background: #0094ff">
            <div id="leftdiv2" class="leftdiv">Active?</div>
            <div id="rightdiv2" class="rightdiv"><asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsActive" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainFirst
        {
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 1%;
            height: 90px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #808080;
        }
        .mainSecond
        {
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 1%;
            height: 25px;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #808080;
        }

        .leftdiv
        {
            width: 25%;
            height: 85px; 
        }

        .rightdiv
        {
            width: 73%;
            height: 30px;   
        }
```

Displays:

[image]

Why are they not lining up correctly?

Comment: use <SPAN> instead of <DIV> for your nested DIVs (i.e. left and right DIVs)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the assistance :) All of them are workable, but I went with the `display` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because div elements are displayed in "block" format as opposed to "inline-block" format. This means that divs try to stack vertically. You could use

```
float: left;
```

to overcome this, or you could add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to both the .leftdiv and .rightdiv classes.

Here's some more information from CSS-Tricks about how the display property works.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: `inline-block` can be better here

Answer (score 1):

You will need to float the `leftdiv` and `rightdiv` classes otherwise they will display on new lines.

```
.leftdiv {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 30px; 
}

.rightdiv {
    float: left;
    width: 73%;
    height: 30px;   
}
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4qf2fc/)

Answer (score 1):

Change the css of the following classes to:

```
.leftdiv
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 85px; 
}

.rightdiv
{
    float: left;
    width: 73%;
    height: 30px;   
}
```

But, between each parent div, add a div with the class:

```
.clearfix 
{
    clear: both;
}
```

So, the markup will be:

```
 <div id="dvFirst" class="mainSecond" style="background: #6FA5FD;">
        <div id="leftdiv3" class="leftdiv">Client: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv3" class="rightdiv"><select class="chosen-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="dvSecond" class="mainSecond" style="background: #f00">
        <div id="leftdiv4" class="leftdiv">Site: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv4" class="rightdiv"><select class="chosen-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div id="dvThird" class="mainSecond" style="background: #808080">
        <div id="leftdiv5" class="leftdiv">Provider: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv5" class="rightdiv"><select class="chosen-select"></select></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="dvFourth" class="mainFirst" style="background: #b6ff00">
        <div id="leftdiv1" class="leftdiv">Message: </div>
        <div id="rightdiv1" class="rightdiv"><textarea cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div id="dvFifth" class="mainSecond" style="background: #0094ff">
        <div id="leftdiv2" class="leftdiv">Active?</div>
        <div id="rightdiv2" class="rightdiv"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<label>` instead. Change your HTML to this one:

```
<div id="dvFirst" class="mainSecond" style="background: #6FA5FD;">
    <label>Client: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCliNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select" ></asp:DropDownList></label>
</div>

<div id="dvSecond" class="mainSecond" style="background: #f00">
    <label>Site: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSitNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></label>
</div>

<div id="dvThird" class="mainSecond" style="background: #808080">
    <label>Provider: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProNewMsg" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="chosen-select"></asp:DropDownList></label>
</div>

<div id="dvFourth" class="mainFirst" style="background: #b6ff00">
    <label>Message: <asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></label>
</div>

<div id="dvFifth" class="mainSecond" style="background: #0094ff">
    <label>Active? <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsActive" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" /></label>
</div>
```

This code is easier to read and maintain.